# is there any way to pass a json key as string @Input() in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material autocomplete to create custom component so i can use it anywhere in my code for that i am passing dynamic arrays and for every array there are different keys i got stuck at one point.

what i tried is

**app.component.html**

```
<app-autocomplete [items]="data.attributes" [field]="'caption.default'" inputType="text" inputPlaceholder="placeholder"></app-autocomplete>
```

**autocomplete.component.ts**

```
var str1="";   
     var length= this.field.split(".");
     str1= "'"+length[0]+"']";
     console.log(length.length)
    for(var i=1;i<length.length;i++){

      if(i===length.length-1){
        str1= str1+"['"+length[i];
      }else{
        str1= str1+"['"+length[i]+"']";
      }

    }

    this.field=str1;
     console.log(this.field);
```

so it will return me ['abc']['xyz']

**autocomplete.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="{{inputType}}" placeholder="{{inputPlaceholder}}" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of items " [value]="option">
        {{option[field]}} 
      </mat-option> 
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I also try with " . " 
like : "caption.default"

it's not working can anybody pls help me to solve this ...!!!

I am trying to do my component generic so anywhere i can use just fill some data @Inputs like if i have two json

**JSON-1**

```
[{
    "caption": {
        "default": "Asset ID"
      }
},
{
    "caption": {
        "default": "Asset ID"
      }
}]
```

and My second json is 
**JSON-2**

```
[{
    "name": {
        "anything": "Asset ID"
      }
},
{
    "name": {
        "anything": "Asset ID"
      }
}]
```

so for my first json-1 I will use like this

```
<app-autocomplete [items]="data.attributes" [field]="'caption.default'" inputType="text" inputPlaceholder="placeholder"></app-autocomplete>
```

and for second json-2 I will use like this

```
<app-autocomplete [items]="data.attributes" [field]="'name.anything'" inputType="text" inputPlaceholder="placeholder"></app-autocomplete>
```

means i want to pass the fields so it can traverse automatically and show me data

Comment: What is it you are trying to do, or what is it supposed to do? Is field supposed to be the path to something in your object?

Comment: hey @ukn i have updated my question can u pls check now

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that but the function should be a pipe or the data needs to be computed at the beginning(when the input of the data is triggered using a setter)

```
fields: Array<string> = [];

    // build an array with your path
    @Input() set field(fields: string) {
        this.fields = fields.split('.');
    }

    // function to retreive the data
    // You need to make this a pipe 
    getValue(option: any): string {
        let temp: any;
        if (this.fields.length > 0 && option) {
            this.fields.forEach(field => {
                temp = option[field];
            })
        }
    return temp;
    }
```

html

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of items " [value]="option">
    {{ getValue(option) }} 
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but this is not working @ukn :) keep helping

Answer (score 0):

simple solution, but read further to know where it went wrong

change

```
this.fields = field.split(".");
{{option[field]}} --->  {{option[fields[0]][fields[1]]}}
```

Let me simplify this,

you are basically trying to access an inner attribute of a object which is a part of array,
hence the attempt to pass the field data and grab it directly,

with respect to items it should have been

```
items[index][ObjectAttr][innerObjAttr]
```

for your sample JSON1 it should be

```
`items[index][caption][default]`
```

but what you are doing instead is

```
items[index][[caption][default]]
```

which will not work

Answer (score 0):

I found ans thanks @ukn and @shrivenkata pavan kumar mhs

```
getValue(Obj): any {
    var objPath=this.field.split(".");
      var s="Obj";
      for(var i=0;i<this.field.split(".").length;i++){
       s=s+"['"+objPath[i]+"']";
      }
     return eval(s);
    }
```